# Tkinter: window doesn't open

Tags: python, tkinter

That's my code and the subfunction is executed, but it doesn't get to mainloop().
If i comment out "update_Lux(labelLuxValue)" the window shows up.
I can't figure out why :(

```
from Tkinter import *

def update_Lux(label):
    label.config(text = str(dev.calcLux()))
    label.after(100, update_Lux(label))

def update_CT():
    labelCTValue.config(text = str(dev.calcCT()))
    labelCTValue.after(100, update_CT())

box = Tk()
box.title('TCS3490')
box.geometry('200x180')

labelLux = Label(master=box, text='Lux=')
labelLux.place(x=5, y=5, width=60, height=30)

labelCT = Label(master=box, text='CT=')
labelCT.place(x=5, y=30, width=60, height=30)

labelLuxValue = Label(master=box)
labelLuxValue.place(x=50, y=5, width=100, height=30)

labelCTValue = Label(master=box)
labelCTValue.place(x=50, y=30, width=100, height=30)

update_Lux(labelLuxValue)

box.mainloop()
```

Comment: might calcLux() be taking too much time? What happens if you increase your 100 to 2000 or more?

Answer (score 2):

You have infinite loops in your two methods `update_Lux` and `update_CT`.

This line

```
label.after(100, update_Lux(label))
```

should be

```
label.after(100, lambda: update_Lux(label))
```

or

```
label.after(100, update_Lux, label)
```

Otherwise you are passing not the `update_Lux` function to `after`, but the *result* of `update_Lux(label)`... and when that method is called, it again tries to pass the result to after, and so on and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that worked well.
I have another problem now.
There is another function called "update_CT". The structure is the same.
Both in sequence won't work.

Including both in one "update" function like:

```
def update_LuxCT():
    labelLuxValue.config(text = str(dev.calcLux()))
    labelCTValue.config(text = str(dev.calcCT()))
    labelLuxValue.after(100, lambda:update_LuxCT())
```

works though :)

But why won't they work separately together?